# How can I debug a failing Capifony deploy due to assetic:dump process time time out?

Tags: javascript, deployment, symfony, yui, capifony

```
$ cap deploy
```

is failing and here is the snippet from the failed output

> ```
>  * executing "cd /var/www/site/prod/releases/20120831164520 && php app/console assetic:dump web --env=prod --no-debug"
>  servers: ["site.me"]
>  [site.me] executing command  
>  ** [out :: site.me] Dumping all prod assets.  
>  ** [out :: site.me] Debug mode is off.
> ......
>  ** [out :: site.me] [file+] web/js/compiled/c9751db.js
> *** [err :: site.me] [RuntimeException]
> *** [err :: site.me] The process timed out.
> ```

I ran the `php app/console assetic:dump web --env=prod` command locally and there are no problems.

I also checked the relevant pre-complied JS file on JSLint and there were no errors.

Here is how I embed the problem JS file into my template

```
{% javascripts 
    '@SoopDesignBundle/Resources/public/js/*.js'
    filter='yui_js'
    output='js/compiled/*.js' 
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I'm not sure how to work out where the problem is. In the past there has been a missing `;` or something that would cause yui_js to falter, but I can't think what else to try.

Comment: Does the `asset:dump` command work on the server on its own? Check the error message it gives you back - btw twig code is right.

Answer (score 7):

capifony comes with a debug option

```
cap -d deploy
```

this protocols each step, might help you finding exact source of this error.

Comment: Debug is a great way to see whats going on and also to run your own tests between steps. +1.